# How to read the matrix from file and make some change in it and again write it to the file?

Tags: c++, file-handling

How to read the content of matrix from file to again in the matrix. so I can use it for updating some value in it and again copy this in the matrix ...

In this first, I check that file is empty or not if it is empty then I write a matrix with all values zero, if it is not empty then I read the value from the file and put it into the matrix and then I make some update in it and write it back to the file with updating values...but I unable to read the matrix from file.

Thanks in advance (beginner).

please help me, I tried it so much time but I unable to do it, It is part of my project.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class block{



public:

void inc(int arr[][10])

{ int k;
 cout<<"by how much value do you want to increment the array's values"<<endl;
 cin>>k;
 for(int i=0 ; i<10; i++)
        for(int j  =0 ; j<10 ; j++)
        arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] + k;


        for(int i=0 ; i<10; i++)
        {
            for(int j  =0 ; j<10 ; j++)
            {

        cout<<arr[i][j];
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }


}

    void details(int arr[][10])
    {

        int m1 = 10;
        int n1 = 10;
        int arr1[10][10];

        ifstream fin1;
        fin1.open("array.txt", ios::ate);

        if (!fin1) {
            cerr << strerror(errno) << "\n"; // handle open errors
        }
        if (fin1.tellg() == 0) {
            cout << "NULL" << endl;

            ofstream fout1;
            fout1.open("array.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < m1; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
                    fout1 << arr[i][j];               //if file is empty write
                                                      //matrix with zero value
                    arr1[i][j] = arr[i][j];
                }
            }

            fout1.close();
        }

        else {

            fin1 >> m1 >> n1;

            for (int i = 0; i < m1; i++)        // this is the code of reading of
                for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++)    //matrix from the file
{  
                    fin1 >> arr[i][j];
                    arr1[i][j] = arr[i][j];
                }
        }

        fin1.close();

       inc(arr1);   // updating matrix


        ofstream fout2;
        fout2.open("array.txt", ios::trunc | ios::out);

        for (int i = 0; i < m1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++) {    // write back to its file with 
                                               //updated value 

                arr[i][j] = arr1[i][j];
                fout2 << arr[i][j];
            }
        fout2.close();
    }
};
int main()
{
    block b1;

    int arr[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            arr[i][j] = 0;
    b1.details(arr);
}
```

Comment: You asked a similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67010950/after-reading-the-matrix-from-file-i-wanted-to-update-this-matrix-with-some-calc and I asked you for a [mcve]. Are you actually coding like this or did the copy and paste destroy the code format? You should format your code to make it readable for yourself and for others.

Comment: what is wrong with this code? I m beginner

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem and debug your code. Your code is not complete. It's not formatted. Input data is missing.

Comment: input data is just a matrix with  0 values.

Comment: You're asking for help. Why do you expect others to write the whole boilerplate around your code snippet to be able to help you? Wouldn't it be much more attractive if people could copy and paste a complete code and debug it? Wouldn't it be much more attractive if the code were formatted and readable?

Comment: so you want full code?

Comment: No, I'm asking for a [mcve]. A minimal but complete code that reproduces your problem. If your problem is in reading the matrix it makes no sense to post code that writes the matrix.

Comment: now check it please homie please..

Comment: What's the input that reproduces your problem?

Comment: i unable to read the matrix which is already written in the file , so i can make some update in it and again write it to the file with new updated values

Comment: What's your actual question? Are you asking for a basic tutorial about reading files? Do you have a specific programming question?

Comment: i know how to read from file but I don't know how to read the value of matrix from file

Comment: What's the difference between _"how to read from file"_ and _"how to read the value of matrix from file"_?

Comment: its mean that i able to read the simple data like name of a person or its id , but not matrix

Comment: What's the difference between _"name of a person or its id"_ and 10x10 numeric values? Read the first value, then read the second value, then read the third value, then ...

Comment: You should create and provide a [mcve]. Focus on reading the file. Don't implement anything else. Probably this will already solve your problem.

Comment: my problem is that I m working on a project on the ticket booking system. so for cinema hall booking chairs representation, I m using a matrix, and initially, this matrix having zero value because there is no booking all chairs are empty. so when someone books the seat with its choice of row and column, so I need to update the matrix with value 1 and save it to the file and after it when another person wants to book it so I want that my function uses that same matrix and update it...

Comment: Think about this statement `arr[i][j] = arr[i][j];`  Do you think it is necessary?  Think about what it does.  This very similar to `x = x;`.

Comment: arr1[i][j] = arr[i][j]  , both array are different

Comment: Try to write a code that does nothing but read a matrix from a file. Currently contains much other functionality.

Comment: ok i going to make it minimal wait

Comment: please see it  now

Comment: I formatted your code and you removed my formatting? Are you really working like that? Please use a formatter. Why do you need the function `inc` to read the matrix? Why do you use a class if all members are public?

Comment: [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9sLBe9QkLtq5qB3C) is a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to read a matrix from a file

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    int arr[10][10];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            arr[i][j] = 0;
    
    std::size_t m1 = 10;
    std::size_t n1 = 10;

    std::ifstream fin1("array.txt");

    if (!fin1) {
        std::cerr << std::strerror(errno) << "\n"; // handle open errors
    }

    fin1 >> m1 >> n1;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m1; i++) // this is the code of reading of
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < n1; j++) { //matrix from the file
            fin1 >> arr[i][j];
        }
    fin1.close();
    
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

with input file

```
10
10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
11 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
21 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
31 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
41 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
51 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
61 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
71 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
81 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
91 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```

Comment: thank you and i didnt remove your formatting m just new in coding and in stackoverflow , sorry>>>